# digital read from pin that is on the same arduino?

Tags: arduino

i want to ceck whether a cable is connected or not. So i thought to connect lets say pin 6 to pin 13. Now i set the pinMode of pin 6 to OUTPUT an pinMode of pin 13 to INPUT. Then I used the digitalWrite method to see if there is a connection between pin 13 and 6.

Here is the code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(13, 100);
  Serial.println(analogRead(6));

}
```

Unfortunately this does not work:(

so what else can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you are looking for this code. I hope this can reach your point

```
int pin6 = 6;
int pin7 = 7;
int pin8 = 8;
int pin9 = 9;
int pin10 = 10;
int pin11 = 11;
int pin12 = 12;
int pin13 = 13;

void setup()
{
pinMode(pin6, INPUT);
pinMode(pin7, INPUT);
pinMode(pin8, INPUT);
pinMode(pin9, INPUT);
pinMode(pin10, INPUT);
pinMode(pin11, INPUT);
pinMode(pin12, INPUT);
pinMode(pin13, INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
pin6status = digitalRead(pin6);
pin7status = digitalRead(pin7);
pin8status = digitalRead(pin8);
pin9status = digitalRead(pin9);
pin10status = digitalRead(pin10);
pin11status = digitalRead(pin11);
pin12status = digitalRead(pin12);
pin13status = digitalRead(pin13);

if (pin6status == HIGH)
{Serial.print(PIN6 = CONNECTED);}
else {Serial.print(PIN6 = NOT CONNECTED)}    

if (pin7status == HIGH)
{Serial.print(PIN 7 = CONNECTED);}
else {Serial.print(PIN 7 = NOT CONNECTED);}

if (pin8status == HIGH)
{Serial.print(PIN8 = CONNECTED);}
else {Serial.print(PIN8 = NOT CONNECTED);}    

if (pin9status == HIGH)
{Serial.print(PIN 9 = CONNECTED);}
else {Serial.print(PIN 9 = NOT CONNECTED);}

if (pin10status == HIGH)
{Serial.print(PIN 10 = CONNECTED);}
else {Serial.print(PIN 10 = NOT CONNECTED);}    

if (pin11status == HIGH)
{Serial.print(PIN 11 = CONNECTED);}
else {Serial.print(PIN 11 = NOT CONNECTED);}

if (pin12status == HIGH)
{Serial.print(PIN 12 = CONNECTED);}
else {Serial.print(PIN 12 = NOT CONNECTED);}    

if (pin13status == HIGH)
{Serial.print(PIN 13 = CONNECTED);}
else {Serial.print(PIN 13 = NOT CONNECTED);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were talking about `digitalRead` and `digitalWrite` but in the code `analogRead` and `analogWrite` are used instead.

The `analogWrite` sets `PWM` on pins with `PWM` support. But if you have pin without `PWM` support, it sets `LOW` or `HIGH` (not sure when, it might be if value is bigger than `127` or worst case when it's equal to `255`). And pin `13` usually doesn't support `PWM` on most boards.

Also `analogRead` works only on analog pins (`A0`-`An`). So using pin `6` is not a good idea.